# Direction vector of a line

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

**Information given:**  The line $x = 0 , z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

**What I need to find:** The direction vector.

**Where I'm at:** I just don't really understand how to get a direction vector from two equation.

**The answer to this problem:** Vector $\vec{j}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line is defined by two planes

- $x=0$
- $z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

and a generic point P on the line is in the form $(0,t,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=(0,0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})+t(0,1,0)$ which is known as parametric form of the line equation $P(t)=P_0+t\vec v$ thus by definition the **direction vector** is $$\vec v=(0,1,0)$$

Answer (score 1):

The line is in the $yz$ plain and is parallel to the $y$-axis. A vector parallel to the $y$-axis has its direction vector $\vec{j}$ which is the direction vector of the  $y$-axis.